# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str 'convert the chararter'

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, int

```
Number = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]    
for n in range(0, 20):
      print(Number[n]+1\n)
InputNum3 = input()
Number[InputNum3] = ''.join(str('-'))
```

want:

```
1       2
     3
     4
     .... 20
```

input 2

want:

```
1
      -
      3
      4...20
```

but the result is:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `input` returns a `str` you need to cast it to `int` in order for the indexing to be valid

Comment: Weird, it raises `SyntaxError` for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

`inputNum3 = int(input())`

to get an Integer, you can't access lists by a String as index.

Your variable names should start with lowercase. Generally snakecase too, with all lowercase separated by underscore:

```
number = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
input_num = int(input())
number[input_num] = "-"
```

You don't need the `.join()` here because you want to have just a single character anyway.

You can also fill your `number` list like so:

`number = [x for x in range(20)]`

This is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Lastly, you can just do `print(number)` if you want to print the full list, no need for the `for` loop.

If you want to print all list elements from index `x` to `y` you can use list slicing:

`number[3:15]` for example.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation) for more examples of slices.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, input() returns a string. In Python2, however, input() returns the type you are looking for, an integer. Therefore, you need to cast the input() function to an int, since you are obviously trying to assign a value in the list by index.

```
Number = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]    
for n in range(0, 20):
   print(Number[n]+1\n)

InputNum3 = int(input())
Number[InputNum3] = ''.join(str('-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Number = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]    
for n in range(0, 20):
      print(Number[n]+1\n)
>>InputNum3 = int(input())
Number[InputNum3] = ''.join(str('-'))
```

> input function accept values as string.